# Groupby and agg produce NaNs when used with diff

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an indexed dataset like this

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'C': np.random.randn(4)}, 
                  index = [5,242,12,634])
```

Now I'm trying to get the difference of C by group like so

```
df.groupby('A').agg('diff')
```

which gives me the output

```
    B   C
5   NaN NaN
242 1.0 -2.492028
12  NaN NaN
634 1.0 -0.455332
```

I'm trying to get a resulting dataframe with only 2 rows, which contain the differences like so

```
B   C   
1.0 -2.492028
1.0 -0.455332
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `df.groupby('A').agg('diff').dropna()`

Comment: ``df.groupby('A').agg(np.subtract.reduce)``

Answer (score 0):

First `diff` is not a agg function which will return the same length of out put same as original dataframe , if you would like the diff without `NaN` we should do `dropna`

```
out = df.groupby('A').diff().dropna()
```

Comment: What function would I use to get the differences between two grouped observations?